# IBM x3200 M2 and chaning the CPU

Tags: ibm, cpu-architecture, intel-vt-x

As my server IBM x3200 M2 and CPU (E4600) does not have VT-x for virtualization (I would like to virtualize Windows in XenServer), may I substitute this CPU for some core2duo or core2quad that supports VT-x ? Does the motherboard have to support VT-x as well or it will work ? THank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use the E3110 (dual core), E3320, E3350, or E3360 (all quad core). Contact IBM for instructions, parts, and pricing. Only the E4600 (cheapest option) came without VT-x.